# I have seperate node REST api and separate Angular 4 interface. Can I pass data from this Angular 4 to Separate REST api?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a Separate NodeJS RESTful api and Separate angular 4 interface. Can I pass data that are submitted from the interface to RESTful api by giving path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried call make an service  like as :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  // Uses http.get() to communicate with NodeJs
  getSomeThing() {
    return this.http.get('yourAPIUrl').map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: this approach is using deprecated http. You should use HttpClient from `@angular/common/http`

Comment: but in angular 4.4 it works, tks for your observations !